# Is there a way to list all the available versions in a package on Bintray?

Tags: rest, api, bintray

Is there a way of retrieving all the available versions in a given package on Bintray?

Like how repositories and packages have 'Get repositories' and 'Get packages' respectively.

I know the one way is to go into the UI and look at the version list. But I'm hoping to find an API that does this for me.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Try the get package API:

```
GET /packages/:subject/:repo/:package[?attribute_values=1]

{
  "name": "my-package",
  "repo": "repo",
  "owner": "user",
  "desc": "This package...",
  "labels": ["persistence", "database"],
  "attribute_names": ["licenses", "vcs", "github", ...], (hidden when using 'attribute_values=1' )
  "licenses": ["Apache-2.0"],
  "custom_licenses": ["my-license-1", "my-license-2"],   (only for Premium Account)
  "followers_count": 82,
  "created": "ISO8601 (yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ)",
  "website_url": "http://jfrog.com",
  "rating": 8,
  "issue_tracker_url": "https://github.com/bintray/bintray-client-java/issues",
  "linked_to_repos": [],
  "github_repo": "", (publishers only)
  "github_release_notes_file": "", (publishers only)
  "public_download_numbers": false, (publishers only)
  "public_stats": true, (publishers only)
  "permissions": [],
  "versions": ["0.9", "1.0", "1.0.1", ...],
  "latest_version": "1.2.5",
  "rating_count": 8,
  "system_ids" : [],
  "updated": "ISO8601 (yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ)",
  "vcs_url": "https://github.com/bintray/bintray-client-java.git",
  "attributes": "{"attr1_name":["attr1_value"], "attr2_name":["attr2_value"]}"   (only when 'attribute_values=1')
}
```

https://bintray.com/docs/api/#_get_packages

You can see the versions section of the resulting JSON.

Comment: Thanks! I was playing around with the APIs and found this too.